# Trying to write a service to publish data from serial

Tags: ros, python, serial, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've copied the code from the tutorial "publisher and subscriber", and tried to modify it to read serial data from an an arduino and publish it.
Here is the code for my publisher:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('beginner_tutorials')
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
import serial

def talker():
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String)
    rospy.init_node('talker')
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        ser.readline()
        rospy.loginfo(ser)
        pub.publish(String(ser))
        rospy.sleep(1.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

The code for my listener is unchanged from the tutorial. when I rosrun them both the publisher stop with the following error message:

```
File "/home/pi/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/serial_message/scripts/talker.py", line 22, in 
    talker()
  File "/home/pi/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/serial_message/scripts/talker.py", line 16, in talker
    pub.publish(String(ser))
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/rospy/topics.py", line 796, in publish
    raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: field data must be of type str
```

What is it I'm doing wrong and how and I resolve this issue?
(I'm aware I can ser up the Arduino to publish directly though I'd like to avoid it as that would require a large modification to my Arduino code.)

**Amend:**
After adding the following code:

```
sensor = ser.readline()
rospy.loginfo(sensor)
pub.publish(String(sensor))
```

When I run them both I get the following error from the listener.

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1362846465.102142] bad callback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/rospy/topics.py", line 678, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/pi/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/serial_message/scripts/listener.py", line 8, in callback
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_name() % data.data)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57564/trying-to-write-a-service-to-publish-data-from-serial/) by [ianphil397](https://answers.ros.org/users/4387/ianphil397/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ianphil397](https://answers.ros.org/users/4387/ianphil397/) on 2013-03-09**:
Okay so I need something like

```
data = ser.readline()
```

then

```
pub.publish(String(data))
```

?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-09**:
Your listener printout in loginfo is wrong. This is unrelated to this question. Please open a new one.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-04-30**:
DId your code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are publishing the Serial object instead of the line that you read from it (which you store nowhere).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2